# Handling mysql "ERROR 1062 (23000)"

Tags: mysql

I have a data bulk table with a lot of duplicate entry which it should not have. To remove this I am migrating data from this table to new one with "UNIQUE" constraints.

For example: Let say original table is "abc" and new table is "xyz".

```
mysql>desc abc;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname | varchar(8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname | varchar(8) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select fname,lname from abc;
+-------+-------+
| fname | lname |
+-------+-------+
| A     | B     |
| A     | B     |
| A     | B     |
| C     | D     |
| C     | D     |
+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table xyz (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, fname VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, lname VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,UNIQUE KEY uqn (fname, lname));
```

In new table: xyz, set (fname, lname) is unique.

### My first attempt is simple sql file

```
INSERT INTO xyz (
        fname,
        lname
)
SELECT
        fname,
        lname
FROM
        abc;
```

### Obvious outcome is :

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 3: Duplicate entry 'A-B' for key 'uqn'

### My second involve error handler and procedure (as read from many blogs)

```
drop procedure if exists handlerproc ;
DELIMITER //
create procedure handlerproc(OUT p_end VARCHAR(10))
        begin
                declare CONTINUE handler for sqlstate '23000' SET @b = '- With Errors';

                INSERT INTO xyz
                (
                        fname,
                        lname
                )
                SELECT
                        fname,
                        lname
                FROM
                        abc;

                set p_end := concat('The End ',@b);
        end;
//
DELIMITER ;
call handlerproc(@a);
select (@a);
```

### Now output is not what i expected:

(@a)
The End -

### The multiple question I have is:

1) Output is "The End -", not "The End - With Errors". This means that handler was not even started. What may be cause of this ? 
2) Is "handlerproc" is going to exit from execution when got first error, or keep checking for another records to enter in new table "xyz" ? 
3) In case, it is going to exit datapump when encounter error first time, how I write the function to achieve complete data migration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have entered duplicates , you may consider :`INSERT IGNORE INTO ....SELECT FROM ...`

try that:

```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO xyz (
    fname,
    lname
    )
  SELECT
    fname,
    lname
  FROM
    abc
```

or `INSERT  INTO ....SELECT FROM ...ON DUPLICATE KEY...`

```
  INSERT INTO xyz (
    fname,
    lname
    )
  SELECT
    fname,
    lname
  FROM
    abc 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fname= ...., lname= ....
```

**EDIT:** you have `UNIQUE KEY uqn (fname, lname)` so it cant be duplicates on those two columns together. as they are unique.

Comment: Thanks @echo_Me. It worked. I will use this for now. But still for correction point of view, what am i doing wrong in procedure written ?
Is there is anyway to use handler to know what pair is duplicate and meanwhile pumping data to new table without fail?

Comment: you welcome :) , about the procedure im sure what you are doing but im guessing you didnt define `@a` and im not very familiar with procedures.

Comment: if your problem is solved then consider to mark it in the left of my answer.